# Listing values once with their sum of other values

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, multiple-columns

[image]

As you can see in the image i am listing products from mysql database with these codes:

```
$satis_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM satislar WHERE zno = '".$zno."'");
        $varmi = mysql_num_rows($satis_cek);
                $toplam_tutar   = 0;
                $indirim        = 0;
                $genel_toplam   = 0;                    
                if($varmi == ""){
                $ara_toplam     = 0;
                $indirim_toplam = 0;
                $genel_toplamlar= 0;    
                }else{          
        while ($satis_al = mysql_fetch_array($satis_cek)){
        $sat_fatura_no  = $satis_al['sat_fatura_no'];   
        $personel       = $satis_al['sat_uye_id'];
        $sat_tarih      = $satis_al['sat_tarih'];
        $sat_tip        = $satis_al['sat_tip'];
        $toplam_tutar   += $satis_al['toplam_tutar'];
        $indirim        += $satis_al['indirim'];
        $genel_toplam   += $satis_al['genel_toplam'];

 $fis_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stok_hareketleri WHERE sth_fatura_no = '".$sat_fatura_no."'");
           while ($a= mysql_fetch_array($fis_cek)){
                $sth_stok_kodu  = $a['sth_stok_kod'];
                $sth_adet       = $a['sth_adet'];
                $sth_tutar      = $a['sth_tutar'];

 $stok_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stoklar WHERE sto_RECno = '".$sth_stok_kodu."'");
        while ($stok_al = mysql_fetch_array($stok_cek)){
        $sto_isim = $stok_al['sto_isim'];
                echo' 
                <tr>
                <td align="left">'.$sto_isim.'</a></td>
                <td align="center">'.$sth_adet.'</td>
                <td align="right">'.$sth_tutar.'</td>
            </tr>';}}}}
```

As shown in the image, i try to list Jack Daniel's once and calculate sum of its sold numbers and sum of sold prices and print them in onw html table row.

Forexample:

> Jack Daniel's     2    220.00
>
> Yeni Rakı 70 cl   1    85.00
>
> Fanta 330 ml      1    3.00

I am new on php so i couldn't fix how to display each product once with their sum of sold numbers and sum of prices from same mysql table.

[image]

[image]

[image: Product Details]

Comment: use sum and count with group by product.It will be good if you'll add table structure.

Comment: Possible to write an example query about this?

Comment: yes but you need to show you tables. add link of table images with some columns atleast or search for aggregate functions in mysql.

Comment: Added the part of mysql table at the beginning of question.

Comment: sth_stok_kod is the id of products.

Comment: You need to add all the table which are used for this result you are expecting. add product table also

Comment: what are sth_adet and sth_tutar

Comment: sth_adet = number of sold products ----- sth_tutar = amount of sold products

Comment: Try the added answer and let me know if any issue.

Comment: Wrote the query as an answer. But it gives same result.

Comment: run the query which i have give and see the output.

Comment: I tried it at the beginning but didn't give me any result.

Comment: what is the error you got.

Comment: WHERE stok_hareketleri.sth_fatura_no = '".$sat_fatura_no."' without this i get all sums of sth_adet and sth_tutar in table but i have to put this "where" cause i need to retrieve exact bill numbers' values.. And when i put it i get the same result as in the beginning like Jack 1, Jack 1 ,Rakı,1, Fanta 1.

Comment: echo the sql and see what it prints and run it in mysql to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this: `table1` is product detail table, `table2` is sold item table.

```
select sto_isim,sum(sth_tutar) as sum,sum(sth_adet) as cnt from table1 join table2 on table1.sto_RECno=table2.sth_stok_kod group by sto_RECno
```

This should give single row for each product with sum and count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$tarih2 = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime($_POST['tarih']));
$tarih3 = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime($_POST['tarih']));

$satis_cek = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM satislar WHERE zno = '".$zno."'");
        $varmi = mysql_num_rows($satis_cek);
                $toplam_tutar   = 0;
                $indirim        = 0;
                $genel_toplam   = 0;                    
                if($varmi == ""){
                $ara_toplam     = 0;
                $indirim_toplam = 0;
                $genel_toplamlar= 0;    
                }else{          
        while ($satis_al = mysql_fetch_array($satis_cek)){
        $sat_fatura_no  = $satis_al['sat_fatura_no'];   
        $personel       = $satis_al['sat_uye_id'];
        $sat_tarih      = $satis_al['sat_tarih'];


        $sat_tip        = $satis_al['sat_tip'];
        $toplam_tutar   += $satis_al['toplam_tutar'];
        $indirim        += $satis_al['indirim'];
        $genel_toplam   += $satis_al['genel_toplam'];}


$fis_cek = mysql_query("select sto_isim,sum(sth_tutar) as sum,sum(sth_adet) as cnt from stoklar join stok_hareketleri on stoklar.sto_RECno=stok_hareketleri.sth_stok_kod WHERE stok_hareketleri.sth_create_date >= '".$tarih2."' AND stok_hareketleri.sth_create_date <= '".$tarih3."' AND sth_tip = 'Satış Fişi' group by stoklar.sto_RECno ORDER BY sto_isim ASC");
           while ($a= mysql_fetch_array($fis_cek)){

                $sth_adet       = $a['cnt'];
                $sth_tutar      = $a['sum'];
                $sto_isim       = $a['sto_isim'];


                echo' 
                <tr>
                <td align="left">'.$sto_isim.'</a></td>
                <td align="center">'.$sth_adet.'</td>
                <td align="right">'.$sth_tutar.'</td>
            </tr>';}}
```

I decided to use exact date values and it works without any problem..